# Chronicle Consumer not reading records correctly?

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I am using chronicle-queue (5.16.13) to write and read json values to a chronicle file.
To write objects I use the following in a loop

```
try (final DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
        dc.wire().write(() -> "msg").text("Hallo asdf");
        System.out.println("your data was store to index="+ dc.index());
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Unable to store value to chronicle", e);
        return false;
    }
```

and to read items I do the following call in a loop

```
DocumentContext documentContext;
    do {
        documentContext = tailer.readingDocument();
        currentOffset = documentContext.index();
        System.out.println("Current offset: " + currentOffset);
    } while (!documentContext.isData());
```

What I observe is that the variable `currentOffset`does not change and after some time (depending on the payload size, it seems) the loop goes infinite and the current offset has crazy values.
The output (shortened) for the first loop is

```
Writing 0
your data was store to index=76385993359360
Writing 1
your data was store to index=76385993359361
Writing 2
your data was store to index=76385993359362
Writing 3
your data was store to index=76385993359363
Writing 4
your data was store to index=76385993359364
Writing 5
your data was store to index=76385993359365
Writing 6
your data was store to index=76385993359366
Writing 7
your data was store to index=76385993359367
Writing 8
your data was store to index=76385993359368
Writing 9
your data was store to index=76385993359369
Writing 10
your data was store to index=76385993359370
Writing 11
your data was store to index=76385993359371
Writing 12
your data was store to index=76385993359372
Writing 13
your data was store to index=76385993359373
Writing 14
your data was store to index=76385993359374
Writing 15
your data was store to index=76385993359375
Writing 16
your data was store to index=76385993359376
Writing 17
your data was store to index=76385993359377
Writing 18
your data was store to index=76385993359378
Writing 19
your data was store to index=76385993359379
Writing 20
your data was store to index=76385993359380
Writing 21
your data was store to index=76385993359381
Writing 22
your data was store to index=76385993359382
Writing 23
your data was store to index=76385993359383
Writing 24
your data was store to index=76385993359384
Writing 25
your data was store to index=76385993359385
Writing 26
your data was store to index=76385993359386
```

And for the second loop

```
Reading 0
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 1
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 2
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 3
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 4
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 5
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 6
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 7
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 8
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 9
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 10
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 11
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 12
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 13
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 14
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 15
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 16
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 17
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 18
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 19
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 20
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 21
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 22
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 23
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 24
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 25
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
```

Am I doing something completely wrong?
Can then anyobody hint me to the correct usage?

Thanks a lot!

## Edit: Added minimal working example

The following unit test fails for me.

```
@Test
public void fails() throws Exception {
    String basePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    String path = Files.createTempDirectory(Paths.get(basePath), "chronicle-")
            .toAbsolutePath()
            .toString();
    logger.info("Using temp path '{}'", path);

    SingleChronicleQueue chronicleQueue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder
            .single()
            .path(path)
            .build();

    // Create Appender
    ExcerptAppender appender = chronicleQueue.acquireAppender();

    // Create Tailer
    ExcerptTailer tailer = chronicleQueue.createTailer();
    tailer.toStart();

    int numberOfRecords = 10;

    // Write
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRecords; i++) {
        System.out.println("Writing " + i);
        try (final DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
            dc.wire().write(() -> "msg").text("Hello World!");
            System.out.println("your data was store to index=" + dc.index());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to store value to chronicle", e);
        }
    }
    // Read
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRecords; i++) {
        System.out.println("Reading " + i);
        DocumentContext documentContext = tailer.readingDocument();
        long currentOffset = documentContext.index();
        System.out.println("Current offset: " + currentOffset);

        Wire wire = documentContext.wire();

        if (wire != null) {
            String msg = wire
                    .read("msg")
                    .text();
        }
    }

    chronicleQueue.close();
}
```

Output is

```
Writing 0
your data was store to index=76385993359360
Writing 1
your data was store to index=76385993359361
Writing 2
your data was store to index=76385993359362
Writing 3
your data was store to index=76385993359363
Writing 4
your data was store to index=76385993359364
Writing 5
your data was store to index=76385993359365
Writing 6
your data was store to index=76385993359366
Writing 7
your data was store to index=76385993359367
Writing 8
your data was store to index=76385993359368
Writing 9
your data was store to index=76385993359369
Writing 10
your data was store to index=76385993359370
Reading 0
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 1
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 2
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 3
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 4
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
Reading 5
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
Reading 6
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
Reading 7
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
Reading 8
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
Reading 9
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
Reading 10
Current offset: -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: You should use try-with-resource on the DocumentContext, however, it's not obvious in this case what you are doing wrong. I suspect it's in how you call this code.  Can you provide a complete unit test?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, can you please see my comment on the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DocumentContext is intended to be one of the lower level interfaces and not to everyone's taste. I favour using the MethodReader/MethodWriter approach unless you have a reason to work at the lower level.

```
@Test
public void works() {
    String path = OS.TMP + "/chronicle-" + System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Using temp path " + path);

    try (SingleChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder
            .single()
            .path(path)
            .build()) {

        ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
        Messager messager = appender.methodWriter(Messager.class);

        int numberOfRecords = 10;

        // Write
        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRecords; i++) {
            System.out.print("Writing " + i);
            messager.msg("Hello World!");
            System.out.println(", your data was stored at index=" + appender.lastIndexAppended());
        }

        ExcerptTailer tailer = queue.createTailer();
        MethodReader reader = tailer.methodReader((Messager) msg -> {
            System.out.println("Current offset: " + tailer.index()
                    + " msg: " + msg);
        });

        // Read
        while (reader.readOne()) {
            // busy wait.
        }
    }
}
```

This prints

```
Using temp path C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\/chronicle-412979753710181
[main] DEBUG net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedFile - Allocation of 0 chunk in C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\chronicle-412979753710181\metadata.cq4t took 15.418 ms.
[main] DEBUG net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedFile - Allocation of 0 chunk in C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\chronicle-412979753710181\20181226.cq4 took 25.061 ms.
Writing 0, your data was stored at index=76841259892736
Writing 1, your data was stored at index=76841259892737
Writing 2, your data was stored at index=76841259892738
Writing 3, your data was stored at index=76841259892739
Writing 4, your data was stored at index=76841259892740
Writing 5, your data was stored at index=76841259892741
Writing 6, your data was stored at index=76841259892742
Writing 7, your data was stored at index=76841259892743
Writing 8, your data was stored at index=76841259892744
Writing 9, your data was stored at index=76841259892745
Writing 10, your data was stored at index=76841259892746

Current offset: 76841259892736 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892737 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892738 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892739 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892740 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892741 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892742 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892743 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892744 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892745 msg: Hello World!
Current offset: 76841259892746 msg: Hello World!
[main] DEBUG net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder - File released C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\chronicle-412979753710181\20181226.cq4
[main] DEBUG net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder - File released C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\chronicle-412979753710181\20181226.cq4
```

NOTE: This writes the same data as the original post.

An advantage of using this interface approach is that you can implement your business component entirely using interfaces of methods with DTOs and not use Chronicle (or at transport) at all. This simplifies testing business logic as you remove the transport from the tests.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But I just added nano timestamps in this code into the Messager ( having separated the appender and tailer into separate threads that start and run concurrently ) and I noticed latencies of the order of > 50,000 micros ( yes 50 thousand micros ). Somethings not correct with the way i am using or is this the case of messages not getting written to the memory store as quickly as possible ? ( Mac i5 , 4 threads , 8 GB RAM ) and I did let the JVM warmup happen by increasing total number of messages to be 10 Million and ignoring first 100K.

Comment: @Bhaskar This most likely happens on a file roll. e.g. see the first logs I have included `net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedFile - Allocation of 0 chunk in C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\chronicle-412979753710181\20181226.cq4 took 25.061 ms.` Two ways to avoid this are to either a) create a file with a chunk size you will never fill b) use the pretoucher to reduce the cost of such delays. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/queue/impl/single/Pretoucher.java

Comment: @Bhaskar For production I would suggest Linux with an SSD, Windows if you must, but none of our clients use Mac servers for production.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey. I played with the block size and also added some busy wait for the appender so it would spin wait for 3 to 5 micros on each append , and now the latencies are considerably down. There is still some jitter but i think thats down to my machine's CPUs and not Chronicle itself. Thanks again for the guidance.

Comment: I suggest you run my MicroJitterSampler to get an idea of how much CPU scheduling delays your machine gets. try it with no other load and when running your benchmark. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity/blob/master/affinity/src/main/java/net/openhft/affinity/MicroJitterSampler.java

Comment: @PeterLawrey we observed problems when the Machine Chronicle is running on is turned off hard. This leads to corruptions of logfiles, I guess. Is there any possiblity to go around that?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself using the Suggestion from @PeterLawrey and wrapping the Document Context in try-with-resources. This solves the issue.
See the corrected snippet below

```
@Test
public void works() throws Exception {
    String basePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    String path = Files.createTempDirectory(Paths.get(basePath), "chronicle-")
            .toAbsolutePath()
            .toString();
    logger.info("Using temp path '{}'", path);

    SingleChronicleQueue chronicleQueue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder
            .single()
            .path(path)
            .build();

    // Create Appender
    ExcerptAppender appender = chronicleQueue.acquireAppender();

    // Create Tailer
    ExcerptTailer tailer = chronicleQueue.createTailer();
    tailer.toStart();

    int numberOfRecords = 10;

    // Write
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRecords; i++) {
        System.out.println("Writing " + i);
        try (final DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
            dc.wire().write(() -> "msg").text("Hello World!");
            System.out.println("your data was store to index=" + dc.index());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to store value to chronicle", e);
        }
    }
    // Read
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRecords; i++) {
        System.out.println("Reading " + i);
        try (DocumentContext documentContext = tailer.readingDocument()) {
            long currentOffset = documentContext.index();
            System.out.println("Current offset: " + currentOffset);

            Wire wire = documentContext.wire();

            if (wire != null) {
                String msg = wire
                        .read("msg")
                        .text();
            }
        }
    }

    chronicleQueue.close();
}
```

which produces the expected output

```
Writing 0
your data was store to index=76385993359360
Writing 1
your data was store to index=76385993359361
Writing 2
your data was store to index=76385993359362
Writing 3
your data was store to index=76385993359363
Writing 4
your data was store to index=76385993359364
Writing 5
your data was store to index=76385993359365
Writing 6
your data was store to index=76385993359366
Writing 7
your data was store to index=76385993359367
Writing 8
your data was store to index=76385993359368
Writing 9
your data was store to index=76385993359369
Writing 10
your data was store to index=76385993359370
Reading 0
Current offset: 76385993359360
Reading 1
Current offset: 76385993359361
Reading 2
Current offset: 76385993359362
Reading 3
Current offset: 76385993359363
Reading 4
Current offset: 76385993359364
Reading 5
Current offset: 76385993359365
Reading 6
Current offset: 76385993359366
Reading 7
Current offset: 76385993359367
Reading 8
Current offset: 76385993359368
Reading 9
Current offset: 76385993359369
Reading 10
Current offset: 76385993359370
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: What exactly was the issue ? how was it fixed using try-with-resources ?

Comment: @Bhaskar I'm not sure... I guess there is something important done in the close. Try with resource calls that automatically and my first version did not.

Comment: I know that the close of try-with-resources will cause the data to be written to the header , but it would be only correct to have an explicit way to do this - this should not be just some black-box magic IMO. May be @PeterLawrey can clarify ?

Comment: @Bhaskar All the examples in the documentation, show you need `try (final DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument())` or you have to call close() yourself. Without calling close(), it will not actually commit the write. In exactly the same manner, all the reading examples show `try (DocumentContext documentContext = tailer.readingDocument())` or you have to close() this yourself.  This isn't just for consistency but allows the library to efficiently perform housekeeping at the right point. Without calling `close()` it will not behave correctly either.